# How to customise Angular Treeview nodes with bell icon

Tags: css, angularjs, fonts, treeview

I have to modify a tree view (http://alexsuleap.github.io/) instance so that a node is updated, after other data on the page is loaded, with a bell icon. Specifically the icon is `glyphicon glyphicon-bell` from the `Glyphicons Halflings` font in AngularJS.

I was thinking that I could simply update the text of a tree node and add a span with the `glyphicon glyphicon-bell` class, but this gets rendered as text, of course.

What would be the most appropriate way to modify a node to show this `glyphicon glyphicon-bell` or "bell icon" at the start of each tree node, in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to find the tree node span with JQuery and add a span with the proper class before it. I added a function to remove the bellicon span, as well.

```
        $scope.addBellIconTo = function(treeNode) {
            var bellIconSpans = $('#' + treeNode.nodeId).prev().find('#bellicon');
            if (bellIconSpans.length == 0) {
                var titleNode = $('#' + treeNode.nodeId).prev().find('.node-name');
                titleNode.before("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-bell' id='bellicon'></span>");
            }
        }

        $scope.removeBellIconFrom = function(treeNode) {
            var bellIconSpans = $('#' + treeNode.nodeId).prev().find('#bellicon');
            while (bellIconSpans.length > 0) {
                bellIconSpans[0].remove();
            }
        }
```